# Including C libraries in Lua

Tags: c, lua

Most of the [examples online](http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/lua/lua_lua_calls_c.htm) of C-to-Lua implementations show the C program messing around with Lua States and Compilers and even compiling both files in a special way to work properly.

But is there a way to call a C function from Lua without the C program knowing it will be used in a Lua program?

I mean something like loading a Lua library: to do that, I just call

```
module = require("/path/library")
module.doSomething()
```

from a standard Lua interpreter, while the examples of C-to-Lua I found online say not only you have to modify your C program to fit whit Lua, but you also need to compile them in a special way and things like that.

So, again, is it possible to call a C function from a standard Lua interpreter whitout the C module knowing it will be used in Lua?

I don't know if it can be of any help, but I'm using LuaJIT.

Comment: LuaJIT supports FFI.

Comment: Oh crap I feel so dumb now.

Comment: There also LUAFFI and alien libraries to work with regular Lua. Ant there also binding to Tiny C(libtcc).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [FFI library](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi.html) that is integrated into LuaJIT.